# I created REST API for SQL SERVER to get the all the record using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is code of Node.js for getting the data from SQL server but it give an error 
"Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first."

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var sql = require("mssql");
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: '',
        server: '',
        database: 'Test' 
    };
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from TestTable', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Comment: have you tried calling sql.close after sql.connect ?

Comment: I write line sql.close() before sql.connect its work thanks @ mnemosdev

Comment: would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `sql.close()` to your code after `sql.connect()` and it should work.